# How to create a persistent custom icon in the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons, user-interface

Changing the icon of a shortcut in the Windows 7 taskbar is easy using the *Properties* menu.

But when the application runs, its icon in the taskbar switches back to the application's default icon.

Is there a way to have the custom icon "stick" so that it does not switch back the default icon when while the application is running?

As a simple example, let's say you create a shortcut to `"notepad.exe example.txt"`.  You then change the icon via the shortcut's *Properties* menu.  Finally, you pin the shortcut to the taskbar.  *All is good,* and your custom icon will appear in the taskbar.  But as soon as you press your new button in the taskbar, the icon will switch back.  How can this be prevented?

*I do not want to hack the executable to change its icon resource.  That would require separate copies of the executable for each file represented on the taskbar, and will not work with signed executables.*

Comment: In windows, documents don't really have an icon, save the one assigned by the filetype association, so I don't think you will be able to do this. some filesystems may allow an icon reference to be applied to a file directly, NTFS doesn't, and there isn't a database that maps file paths to icons, so teh OS just assigns them by type. Shortcuts (.lnk) files do support iconography, but the shortcut yields to the application when launched. the App draws its own icon on the form, and the jumplist picks up on it. Sorry.

Comment: @FrankThomas wrote: *...Shortcuts (.lnk) files do support iconography but the shortcut yields to the application when launched. The App draws its own icon on the form, and the jumplist picks up on it...*  That summarizes the issue perfectly!

Comment: @RandySchuman Yes. That tutorial is excellent, but it leaves out a key issue: *what happens when one of those icons is clicked*.

Comment: @RandySchuman Sorry, my comment was ambiguous.  I tested the method described in that tutorial, and it had the same problem.  But if you test it, and can confirm my findings (or discover that I made an error), that will be helpful! :)

Comment: @RandySchuman Thanks Randy.  I look forward to your findings.

Comment: I see what you mean. The icon is being overlayed with what is called a "label". I had to go into the taskbar properties and set it to "always combine, hide labels". If you want it to not combine, I had to use a 3rd party utility called "7+ Taskbar Tweaker". It has to run in the background.