# Possible to create a shortcut to open Notepad++ with a specific tab?

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++, tabs, file-shortcut

Let's say you have Notepad++ open with `a.cpp` in tab #1 and `b.cpp` in tab #2.  Let's also say tab #2 is the active tab.

Is it possible to create a Windows 7 shortcut to open Notepad++ with `a.cpp` as the active tab (in the above scenario)?  The shortcut must work in the Windows 7 taskbar.

Comment: If `a.cpp` is always the first tab then `Notepad++ a.cpp` will activate that tab (tab #1).

Comment: You might be able to do this with a startup macro. See [Auto start Notepad++ macro](https://superuser.com/q/411018)

Comment: @DavidPostill Interestingly, a shortcut to `Notepad++ a.cpp` seems to activate the appropriate tab, but once that shortcut is placed in the Windows 7 taskbar, it no longer works like that.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't try putting it in the taskbar. That might be related to this [How to create a persistent custom icon in the Windows taskbar?](https://superuser.com/q/1121036)

Comment: @DavidPostill I've been trying to determine if it's related, and I'm not sure yet.  Placing multiple shortcuts to Notepad++ with filename parameters in the Windows 7 taskbar creates some odd behavior.  Give it a try, and you'll probably see the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work quite like you described.

[Here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) is a list of notepad-plus-plus command line arguments and options.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that I read that before posting.  I don't see any way to select which tab should be active via the command line.

Comment: Thats because **there is no way to do that**. Its not been implemented. Only workaround i can imagine is if you open multiple files and jump to a line within one of the files you opened within the same command. Please accept my answer.

Comment: @MasterAzazel Asking someone to accept your answer is bad etiquette (when they are not a completely new user who may not know how to accept).